# How to query data from json in c# windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

I am new to windows phone dev. I'm working on an app that fetch json from a web service and parse it and display it to the app. I used json.net to parse it. here's my json file:

```
[
{
    "id": "001",
    "title": "title1",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "3",
    "image": "defaultimg.jpg"
},

{
    "id": "021",
    "title": "title2",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "1",
    "image": "defaultimg2.jpg"
},

{
    "id": "011",
    "title": "title3",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "3",
    "image": "defaultimg22.jpg"
},

{
    "id": "008",
    "title": "title24",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "2",
    "image": "defaultimg12.jpg"
},
{
    "id": "121",
    "title": "title12",
    "content": "sample content",
    "category_id": "3",
    "image": "defaultimg27.jpg"
}
]
```

so I came up with this class with the help of json2csharp.com

```
    public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

here's my code in cs

```
 var data = new WebClient();
            Observable
              .FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(data, "DownloadStringCompleted")
              .Subscribe(r =>
              {
                  var deserialized =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
                  ListBox1.ItemsSource = deserialized;
              });
            data.DownloadStringAsync(
              new Uri("http://sampleurl.com/xyz/myjson.aspx"));
```

I want to display only those who has "category_id": "9" on the listbox1
can you help me how to filter this data? im a student and new in c# windows phone. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you provide the code you have tried to display them?

Comment: I just tried this syntax what @jbabey gave me:

ListBox1.ItemsSource = deserialized.Where(r => r.category_id == 9);

"A local variable named 'r' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'r', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: Ok, cool! You can always use the "edit" link button to add those information into your original post. People usually write "Edit" in bold and then add missing info :) Remember you can always Edit your own post :) Welcome on SO btw, I suggest you also have a look to our Help section if you want to learn more about the community : http://stackoverflow.com/help Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally want to use [LINQ](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) to manipulate your `List<RootObject>`, something like:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(r.EventArgs.Result);

// select only RootObjects with category_id equal to 9
ListBox1.ItemsSource = deserialized.Where(r => r.category_id == 9);
```

Comment: Hi @jbabey, I tried your syntax and it gives me this error:

A local variable named 'r' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'r', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: @LadzAngeles then change it to a different name.

Answer (score 0):

If the API itself does not have an endpoint that allows you to query for only those records with `category_id : 9` then you'll have to do the filtering at the client to populate your listbox.  One common and easy way to do that is with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx).

Here is an example of what the LINQ syntax would look like:

```
  var categoryNineOnly = data.Where(x=>x.category_id == 9)
```

Much more detail here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx